# MomentJS Parsing big data string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

So, I have this kind of data
`startTime: Fri Dec 28 2018 01:15:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`
and this
`endTime: Mon Dec 31 2018 02:15:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`
The data is always in this format. I need to parse it so I can have an array of objects with every day with all the days between startTime and endTime at the hours of startTime and endTime (1:15 - 2:15 in this case) 
Any ideeas? I have got an answer which is

```
function toDays(startDateString, endDateString) {

  const startDate = moment(startDateString, 'dddd MMM DD YYYY');
  const endDate = moment(endDateString, 'dddd MMM DD YYYY');

  const dates = [];

  while(startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate, 'day')) {
    let currentDay = startDate.format('dddd');
    dates[currentDay] = [];
    dates[currentDay].push({start:'9:00', end:'18:00'});
    startDate.add(1, 'days');
  }

  return dates;
}

const result = toDays('Mon Dec 24 2018', 'Fri Dec 28 2018');
console.log(result);
```

But i cannot really use it, I'm not really sure how to fix this as I have never worked with moment before.

Comment: Please show example of the expected results.

Comment: Excepted result would be [ Friday{ startTime: 9:00, endTime: 18:00} , ... all the way to Monday{ startTime: 9:00 , endTime:18:00 } ];

Comment: OK but that's not a valid structure. You probably want more like `[{day:'Friday',start:'9:00',end:'18:00'},{day:Saturday',start:'9:00',end:'18:00'}]`

Comment: Yeah, something along the lines :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, you're probably having trouble figuring out how to parse the format `startTime: Fri Dec 28 2018 01:15:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`?
If this is indeed the case then I think the following code might help:

```
<script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.23.0/moment.js'></script>
<script>
function toDays(startDateString, endDateString) {
  const formatString = 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ [(Eastern European Standard Time)]';
  const startDate = moment(startDateString, formatString).utcOffset("+02:00");
  const endDate = moment(endDateString, formatString).utcOffset("+02:00");
  const start = startDate.format('H:mm');
  const end = endDate.format('H:mm');

  const dates = [];

  while(startDate.isSameOrBefore(endDate, 'day')) {
    let currentDay = startDate.format('dddd');
    dates.push({day: currentDay, start: start, end: end});
    startDate.add(1, 'days');
  }

  return dates;
}

const result = toDays('Fri Dec 28 2018 01:15:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)', 'Mon Dec 31 2018 02:15:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)');
console.log(result);
</script>
```

Main point is that the line `const formatString = 'ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss [GMT]ZZ [(Eastern European Standard Time)]';` parses the date format you provided properly.

Answer (score 1):

Add the day name to the new object you create as a property like `day` and push that whole object into the array

Change

```
dates[currentDay] = [];
dates[currentDay].push({start:'9:00', end:'18:00'});
```

To

```
dates.push({ day: currentDay, start:'9:00', end:'18:00'})
```